# Shrinkwrap modifier has no target available, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, shrinkwrap

[image: Bezier curve and my shrinkwrap setting. when I click the Target dropdown, there are not objects and manual select does not work either]

Hiya! I am extremely new Blender, and in particular Bezier curves. I found a tutorial which shows how I could use the shrinkwrap modifier to snap the "ribbon" around another object, so I was hoping to do that here.

I have created a bezier curve and have adjusted to preferred general features to what I am after, but when I've tried to add the Shrinkwrap modifier and select a target, I am unable to.

I am sure it's likely an error on my end but I am struggling to figure what I've done wrong as I'm completely new to Bezier curves as a whole hahah.

If someone could help out that would be awesome ~ for context I am making a model for a 3D printing pipeline so Topography mapping etc is not an issue here.

Comment: you can only shrinkwrap on meshes. Is it possible that you have only curves? If you want a precise answer and that we don't have to guess what's going on, it would be very helpful if you edit your question and add a link to the tutorial and upload your blend file -> you can do that by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: ... and if you you're aiming at solving the _particular_ case of a nice regular spiral on a curve... there's a better way.